# Need to ignore zeroes in IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hi i have two columns (D and E) both contain data - both include zeroes in them.

I am looking to write an IF statement categorizing whether there is "Growth" or "decline" over these two columns as one is FY17 and the other is a re forecast. However, I need to ignore the zeroes in both theses columns

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Curious why a forecast has 0's

Comment: Needed to extract all clients not just those who had revenue forcasted against them so some had zero some had values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot your data and simply filter out 0's or you can use the equation:

```
=IF(OR(D2=0,E2=0),"Ignore",IF(D2>E2,"Decline","Growth"))
```

You can swap out `"Ignore"` for anything or just choose to leave the row blank with `Char(32)` or `""`

---

[image]

*Image of output above.*

As expected, the first 3 rows are *'ignored'*. The bottom 2 outputs are intuitive.
Row 5 is where you may get some unexpected results. **IF** there is a possibility of FY17 = FY18, then you will need to adjust equation for this (Replace the `Growth` in equation with one last `IF` statement).